# does the facebook fql application insights table work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm running a few fql queries to try and pull insights data into my own tables where i could display them. The problem is that nothing is returned- here is a sample query

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id='000' AND metric='application_stream_stories' AND end_time = end_time_date('2012-04-02') AND period=period('day')
```

This returns a pair of empty square brackets. It doesn't even return the column names with the zero value.

If i do another query- this time changing the metric- it returns a zero value json array

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id='000' AND metric='application_active_users' AND end_time = end_time_date('2012-04-02') AND period=period('month')
```

and the result-

```
[{"metric":"application_active_users","value":0}]
```

i have tried these queries use php and the fql console on facebook- does this table work (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#application_content) i have cycled through most of the metrics finding nothing working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works, ensure you have the `read_insights` permission. If you don't you will get an empty array. `application_active_users` does not need `read_insights` only a valid access token.

> Any valid `access_token` for the publicly available `application_active_users` metric

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/